# return more than one parameter from a function in C

Tags: c

i have been trying to figure out ways where i can return more than one value from a function in C.

Say for instance i have the

```
int compute(int a, int b)
{
int c;
// do some computation on a,b,c
// return a,b,c
}
```

now i can return these values say in an array, and i was trying to do that and i then i realized that the array needs to be dynamic so it can be referenced in main() as well.

Another way could be that i create a structure and then just return the struct variable.

Is there any simple and robust way of doing this, other than the above work around ? i have to return about 25 different computation values which are independent of each other from a method, and i have a lot structs in my code already.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't easily return more than one variable like, for example, Python with `return (a,b,c)`. However you can pass pointers that are set to the other "return values" or use a struct.

### Out-of-place

If you want a function to actually return separate values and not modify its arguments, a simple way is to pass additional pointers (you could also use structs). e.g. this function will compute the sum and difference of a pair of numbers:

```
int add_sub(int a, int b, int* ret2) {
   if (ret2) *ret2 = a - b;
   return a + b;
}
```

The `if (ret1)` allows you to safely pass `NULL` as the pointer argument, so that you can ignore that return value. You use this like:

```
int add, sub;
add = add_sub(10, 3, &sub);
// add == 13, sub == 7

int just_add;
just_add = add_sub(15, 5, NULL);
// just_add == 20
```

(Note, this technique can lead to confusing behaviour if you pass the same argument twice, e.g. `a = add_sub(a, b, &b)` doesn't give you what want.)

## In-place

If you want to modify the arguments to a function, you can just pass those as pointers. e.g. this function will increment both its arguments and then return their sum:

```
int increment_and_sum(int* a, int* b) {
     (*a)++;
     (*b)++;
     return a + b
}
```

Which you use like:

```
int a = 10, b = 3, sum;
sum = increment_and_sum(&a, &b);
// a == 11, b == 4, sum == 15
```

(Note that you can't use literals in `increment_and_sum`, that is, you can't do `increment_and_sum(3, 4)` or `increment_and_sum(&3, &4)`.)

Comment: thank you, the only reason i was trying to avoid pointers was to avoid getting hopelessly lost in debugging if i messed up my code !

Answer (score 5):

If the values are all logically related, then it makes sense to put them into a structure.  But if you're changing only a few values that aren't tightly coupled, you can pass them as pointers like this:

```
int swap(int *a, int *b) {
  int tmp;

  if (a == b) { // Pointers are equal, so there's nothing to do!
    return -1;  // Indicate the values haven't changed.
  }

  tmp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = tmp;
  return 0;  // Indicate the swap was successful.
}

void main(...) {
  int first = 12;
  int second = 34;

  if (swap(&first, &second) == -1) {
    printf("Didn't swap: %d, %\n", first, second);
  } else {
    printf("Swapped: %d, %d\n", first, second);
  }
}
```

It's a fairly standard technique to put data into the function arguments, and have the function return a value to indicate success/failure, or some other condition.\

Comment: yeah i can use this approach, i can work around it to make it at least less intense then returning a hoard of values using tacky work arounds

Comment: In the "real" code, be sure to check for NULL pointers.  I omitted that to avoid distracting you from the pointer manipulation, but it's important in practice.

Comment: thank you, the only reason i was trying to avoid pointers was to avoid getting hopelessly lost in debugging if i messed up my code ! now i will be extra careful and if i get stuck somewhere i will post the code here to seek help

Comment: Pointers are an important part of the C language.  Used correctly, they contribute flexibility and power.  The sooner you become comfortable writing and debugging code with pointers, the more valuable you'll be as a programmer.  Start simple, and you won't get hopelessly lost.  (Oh, and you _will_ mess up your code now and then; it's an occupational hazard.  Learning how to un-mess it up is also important!)

Comment: Furthermore, with a competent debugger, pointer problems can be tracked down easier than people usually end up thinking. I mean, I don't find it too hard to figure out where boost::auto_ptr's go wrong, raw pointers are a breeze compared to that

Answer (score 2):

Not possible you have to pass pointers to variables and set them in your method. Like so:

```
void get_some_values()
{
    int a=0, b=0, c=0;
    compute(&a, &b, &c);

    // after call to compute a=1, b=2, c=3;
}

void compute(int *a, int *b, int c*)
{
    *a = 1;
    *b = 2;
    *c = 3;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The normal way to do it is with pointer arguments. If you need to return variable numbers of things, you can use a pointer to data and a pointer to an integer "number of things".
Another way to do it is pointer-to-pointer, and have your function allocate memory as needed. This makes the caller responsible for freeing it.

Example:

```
int make_numbers(int **numbers, int *count)
{
  /* work out how many numbers we want to generate */
  *count = howmany;
  *numbers = malloc(*count * sizeof(int));
  /* fill *numbers array here */
  return 0; /* success */
}

void caller(void)
{
  int *numbers;
  int count;
  if (0 == make_numbers(&numbers, &count)) {
    /* use the numbers */
    free(numbers);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*Technically* speaking, a function only returns one value.  Otherwise, it wouldn't be a function (remember mathematical functions?  Same principle here.).

What you can do is:

- Place them in a struct and return the struct, if the elements are related.  Probably the easiest and clearest way to do this.
- Place them in an array and return the array.  About as easy as a struct, but it may not be as clear.
- (Numerical values only) You can use a sort of self-designed map to get them into one integer (a = 100 * a, b = 10 * b, c = c).

Example involving arrays:

```
int* coords(int x, int y) {
    int *a = calloc(sizeof(int), 2);
    a[0] = x;
    a[1] = y;
    return a;
} 

int main() {

    int* vals = coords(47, -121);
    printf("vals = {%d, %d}\n", vals[0], vals[1]);
    return 0;
}

vals = {47, -121}
```

Comment: A mathematical function can return an arbitrary number of values (e.g. vector valued functions, functions that map to sets), it just can't return different output when given the same input. (i.e. for some function `f`, `f(1)` is always the same, no matter when/where/how/why it is called and evaluated.)

Comment: @dbaupp:  That's right.  Here, I'm using the vector style (i.e. placing elements into an array).  I also touch on the mapping a bit as well, although not entirely in a proper mathematical sense.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot but another alternative solution that is more c++ish would be to create a struct then return that.

```
    struct RET_TYPE
    {
        int a;
        int b;
    };

    struct RET_TYPE foo()
    {
         ...

         return RET_TYPE();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also return array using pointers here is the demonstration.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_return_arrays_from_function.htm

Answer (score -1):

If you want no structs you can only pass by reference. Would need good documentation, maybe even declarative programming.

```
void compute(int& a, int& b, int& c) { ... }
void compute(int* a, int* b, int* c) { ... }
```

Comment: You can't pass by reference in C.