# Pointer losing its value + execv compilation warning

Tags: c, pointers, execv

I hope I haven't missed a similar question.

I'm trying to code a mini-shell of my own, using primitive C functions.

I got something that should work, but I have a pointer that makes everything bug.

My `adrCmd` pointer should get the command-path string from the `searchCmd()` function and keep the same value in the `main` function.

In fact: it points to the right value on `searchCmd()`, but not in the `main()`.

Here's the code:

```
    int searchCmd(char* cmd, char* adrCmd){
    char* path = getenv("PATH");
    if(debug)printf("PATH : %s\n", path);
    int nbPath = (compteLettre(path, ':')+1);
    char** pathTab = malloc(nbPath*sizeof(char*));
    decompose(path, pathTab, 2048, ':');

    int i;
    char* adr = malloc(sizeof(char*));
    for(i=0; i<nbPath; i++){
        sprintf(adr, "%s/%s", pathTab[i], cmd);
        if(debug)printf("   source : %s \n", adr);


        int fs = open(adr, O_RDONLY); // Si on peut ouvrir le fichier, c'est qu'il existe ! 
        if(fs != -1){ // si le fichier existe, on le renvoie;
            if(debug){
                printf("Commande trouvée dans path ! \n");
                printf("%s \n", adr);
            }
            adrCmd = adr;
            printf("%s ?= %s \n",adrCmd, adr );// oui
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

/**********************\
        Main
\**********************/

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    printf("Mini-shell : OK \n");

    char cmd[CMDSIZE];
    char** splited = malloc(CMDSIZE*sizeof(char*));
    char* adrCmd = malloc(sizeof(char*));
    char* params;
    while(printf("$ : ") && gets(cmd) && (strcmp(cmd, "exit")!=0 && strcmp(cmd, "quit")!=0)){ // On boucle tant que la commande != "exit" ou "quit"

        printf("Votre commande : %s \n", cmd);
        decompose(cmd, splited, CMDSIZE, ' ');
        if(debug)afficheCmd(splited, CMDSIZE);

        if(!searchCmd(splited[0], adrCmd)){
            printf("Commande n'existe pas, essayez apt-get install %s\n", splited[0]);
        }else{
            if(debug)printf("Execution de la commande '%s' : \n", adrCmd);
            params = splited[1]; // params = array(splited[1], splited[2], ...... )
            if(execv(adrCmd, params) == -1){
                printf("Erreur d'exection de la commande\n");
            }
        }

    }
    printf("Fin du programme %s \n", argv[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's what the execution returns:

```
$ ./a.out 
Mini-shell : OK 
$ : ls /var
Votre commande : ls /var 
CMD[0] = ls 
CMD[1] = /var 
PATH : /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
    source : /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm/ls 
    source : /usr/local/sbin/ls 
    source : /usr/local/bin/ls 
    source : /usr/sbin/ls 
    source : /usr/bin/ls 
    source : /sbin/ls 
    source : /bin/ls 
Commande trouvée dans path ! 
/bin/ls 
/bin/ls ?= /bin/ls 
Execution de la commande '' : 
Erreur d'exection de la commande
```

And while I'm here, when I compile, `execv` returns a warning:

```
$ gcc shell.c 
shell.c: In function ‘main’:
shell.c:113:4: attention : passing argument 2 of ‘execv’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/include/unistd.h:564:12: note: expected ‘char * const*’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
```

What should I do to avoid this?

Comment: Are you sure with this: `char* adrCmd = malloc(sizeof(char*));`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [return more than one parameter from a function in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264681/return-more-than-one-parameter-from-a-function-in-c)

Comment: Well, no !
But when I put it like this :
char* adrCmd;
I get :
Execution de la commande 'UWVS�i'
=> In my main(), adrCmd = "UWVS�i"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C is pass by value. So when doing this

```
 int searchCmd(char * cmd, char * adrCmd){
```

`adrCmd` is a copy of what had been passed in. Overwriting the copy won't change what it had been copied from in the caller.

To fix this pass down the address of `adrCmd`:

```
 int searchCmd(char * cmd, char ** padrCmd){
```

and use it like this:

```
    *padrCmd = adr;
```

Call `searchCmd()` like this:

```
  if(!searchCmd(splited[0], &adrCmd)){
```

and define and initialise `adrCmd` like this;

```
  char * adrCmd = NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !
It solved the problem, and I see what I got wrong ! :p