# "Address out of bound" when accessing second element of a pointer passed to a function

Tags: c, pointers, arguments

I have this function:

```
int scan_arguments(int *words_count, char ***words, char **file)
{
    /* If the first argument is equal to "/f" copy the second argument in the file variable */
    if (*words_count > 2 && !strncmp(*words[0], "/f", 2)) {
        if(!(file = malloc(strlen(*words[1]) + 1))) {
            printf("Allocation error");
            return 1;
        }
        strcpy(*file, *words[1]);
        words += 2;
        words_count -= 2;
}
```

And I call it this way from my main function:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *file = "", **words;
    int words_count;

    /* Copy the arguments and discard the program name */
    words = argv + 1; 
    words_count = argc - 1;

    scan_arguments(&words_count, &words, &file);
}
```

The purpose of my function is to check if the first argument is "/f" and, if it is, store the second argument in the file string.

The problem is that when execution reaches the strlen(*words[1]) part, the program stops working and from the debugger I get "Address out of bound". I can't understand what's the problem, because *words[0] gets evaluated correctly.

Sorry if it is maybe a simple question but it's my first serious program with pointers and I still have some difficulties.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT

Thanks to @BLUEPIXY and @CoolGuy I changed my function to this:

```
/* If the first argument is equal to "/f" copy the second argument in the file variable */
if (*words_count > 2 && !strncmp((*words)[0], "/f", 2)) {
    if(!(*file = malloc(strlen((*words)[1]) + 1))) {
        printf("Allocation error");
        return 1;
    }
    strcpy(*file, (*words)[1]);
    *words += 2;
    *words_count -= 2;
}
```

It now works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: 1)`int main(int argc, char **argc)` won't compile since you have two variables with the same name. 2)`words = argv + 1;` is accessing a invalid memory location. 3) `file = malloc(strlen(*words[1]) + 1))` should be `*file = malloc(strlen((*words)[1]) + 1))` (parenthesis added. See BLUEPIXY's comment below to know why) 4)`words += 2;
        words_count -= 2;` -- You are adding pointers which doesn't make much sense and is wrong.

Comment: `*words[1]` should be `(*words)[1]`. `*words[0]` ditto.

Comment: @CoolGuy 1) It was a digitation error, i edited it. 2) gcc doesn't signal it as a warning even if it's set to -pedantic, but anyways I'll change it if it's incorrect. Thank you for your help

Comment: and `file = ...` --> `*file =..`, `words += 2;
        words_count -= 2;` --> `*words += 2;
        *words_count -= 2;`

Comment: @CoolGuy  3) I'll change it. 4) After I have stored my  `file ` variable I need to have  `words ` pointing to the next element because I won't need the first ones anymore. I'll write  `*words_count -= 2 `, but I don't know what to write for  `words `. Thanks for your help, I'll modify my program and let you know.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thanks for your help, I'll modify my program and let you know

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26680266/694576 (and a partial duplicate, referring "C is pass by vlaue")

Comment: @CoolGuy It now works perfectly. Are you sure that I can't have another pointer pointing to the same location that  `argv` points to? Because neither the compiler signals anything nor I have any problem during execution time.

Comment: @TeoZec "_Are you sure that I can't have another pointer pointing to the same location that argv points to?_" -- When did I say that? Of course you can. But `argv + 1` is not "the same location `argv` points to". It is not the memory location you want. You probably want `words = argv;`. BTW, you should return an `int` from the function (when `malloc` succeeds)

Comment: @CoolGuy Sorry for the misunderstanding. Actually I want  `words` to point to  `argv + 1` to remove the program name from my list, just like I then increment it in  `scan_arguments()`. I thought I could do it because I am accessing an allocated memory location. Oh, and thanks for noting: I actually return 0 at the end of the function but I didn't post all the other code in the function because it doesn't matter for this question.

Comment: @TeoZec Oops. I misunderstood the pointer arithmetic. Sorry for that.